# Help with php random random array

Tags: php, arrays, random

I need help with an array problem I have, so far I have this:

```
$array1 = array('foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4', 'foo5');

$array2 = array('newfoo1', 'newfoo2', 'newfoo3', 'newfoo4', 'newfoo5');

$random1 = array_rand($array2);
$random2 = $array2[$random1];

foreach($array1 as $key){
 echo $key . '<br />';
 echo $random2 . '<br /><br />';
}
```

which outputs:

```
foo1
newfoo4

foo2
newfoo4

foo3
newfoo4

foo4
newfoo4

foo5
newfoo4
```

But I want "newfoo4" (array2) to be a random item so it would output somethng like this:

```
foo1
newfoo3

foo2
newfoo4

foo3
newfoo1

foo4
newfoo5

foo5
newfoo2
```

rather then the same,

**BUT** also allow duplicates of array2 so array1 and array2 do not have to have the same amount items in their arrays ....

so for instance if array1 had 5 items and array 2 only 3 items end result output could be:

```
foo1
newfoo3

foo2
newfoo1

foo3
newfoo3

foo4
newfoo2

foo5
newfoo3
```

...I hope this makes sense to someone  ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array1 = array('foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4', 'foo5');
$array2 = array('newfoo1', 'newfoo2', 'newfoo3', 'newfoo4', 'newfoo5');

foreach($array1 as $key){
    echo $key . '<br />';
    echo $array2[array_rand($array2)] . '<br /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this line

```
$random2 = $array2[array_rand($array2)];
```

into your `foreach` loop, like so:

```
foreach($array1 as $key){
    $random2 = $array2[array_rand($array2)];
    echo $key . '<br />';
    echo $random2 . '<br /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
foreach($array1 as $key){
 $rand_num = rand(0, count($array2));
 echo $key . '<br />';
 echo $array2[$rand_num] . '<br /><br />';
}
```